# Bootstrap remote modal: handling form submit errors and redisplay

Tags: ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying out the "data-remote" feature of a Bootstrap modal, which populates the modal body with the results of an http fetch:

```
<button
type="button"
class="btn btn-success"
data-toggle="modal"
data-remote="/ajax/newthing/10"
data-target="#addThing">

<div class="modal fade" id="addThing" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      PLACEHOLDER1
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It all looks very clean. And it works fine in the happy path.

However the documentation (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/ ) is silent on form and error handling.  If the ajax submit encounters an error, how do I redisplay the modal with the errors highlighted? Client side validation may be part of the mix also, but the question is specific to the server side validation and error path.

Comment: A modal is only a dialog box designed. The error handling method you would use for a page applies to the modal as well. Are you planning to have client-side or server-side validations?

Comment: Let's say server side validation for simplicity (since even with client side validation, you also validate on the server side).

Comment: So you could use AJAX, take all the form fields from the modal, process them at the server, return the errors and display within the modal. I guess you know this already, is there something else you're confused about?

Comment: That's exactly the question above: how do I redisplay the modal on ajax error?